# Telegram bot API sendMessage 400 error(Bad Request: message text is empty) when using python to send request

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

My function:

```
async def send_message(message_text: str, ids: list[int]):
    try:
        load_dotenv(env_path())
        token = bot_secret()
        for id in ids:
            response = requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage", data={
                "chat_id": id, "text": message_text, "parse_mode": "Markdown", "disable_web_page_preview": "true"})
            response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logger.error(err)
```

`message_text` is not empty

If I do this:

```
async def send_message(message_text: str, ids: list[int]):
    try:
        load_dotenv(env_path())
        token = bot_secret()
        for id in ids:
            response = requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage", data={
                "chat_id": id, "text": "simple text", "parse_mode": "Markdown", "disable_web_page_preview": "true"})
            response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logger.error(err)
```

then it works.

Comment: And what exactly is in `message_text`?

Comment: Log/print the message_text and I'm sure you'll see something else than what you expected

Comment: `print(message_text)` output my message: Появился новый issue
[#16
''Titleeee''](https://aa.adev-team.ru/adev/prototype/-/issues/16)
Автор: dmitry_isaev:
''blablabla''